# Need Help Subsetting and Sequentially Labelling a Master Data File in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have a main datafile full of research subjects' information (age, gender, body mass) and would like to generate a new data frame that represents the subject pool every time we added a new subject. So for example we can use this as a representative database:

```
N=30 #total number of subjects 
data=matrix(nrow=N,ncol=4)
data[,1]=1:nrow(data)
for(i in 1:N){
data[i,2]=(sample(0:1,1))
data[i,3]=(sample(18:80,1))
data[i,4]=(sample(18:30,1))
}

data <- as.data.frame(data)
colnames(data)=c("id","sex","age","BMI")
```

I have been trying to figure out the code that would allow me to type in 
something like data_5 and get back a dataframe that is all the columns but just the first 5 rows. So far I have this but it doesn't seem to be correct. Can anybody help?

```
n=nrow(data) #number of rows/subjects
n

for (i in 2:n) {

data[i]=data[i,]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

R has integer subsetting, so you to get the top `5` rows you can do:

```
data[1:5, ]
```

Note that the empty second position means "take every column".